# Execute curl command with variable interpolation

Tags: vimrc, variables, environment-variables

I'm trying to adapt this known-working snippet for installing `vim-plug`:

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC
endif
```

Seeing as I already have `set runtimepath=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim`, I tried:

```
" BROKEN
let vimplug=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME."/vim/.vim/autoload/plug.vim" 
if empty(glob(vimplug))
    silent execute '!curl -fLo '.vimplug.' --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC 
endif
```

Which errors on exit with:

```
> You don't have permission to create /vim
```

which suggests to me that it's evaluating `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to an empty string, but it is set, so this is where I'm stuck.

I added the `execute` because I understood that to be the correct way to evaluate variables before executing a command; what have I missed?

Comment: What is the output of `:echomsg string('!curl -fLo '.vimplug.' --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim')` ?

Comment: Well, clearly the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set. Do you try to set it yourself somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

At least on neovim, something like this should work. It uses [`stdpath()`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/868b84199ef321834022c19d9ba1d1d04cb77570) in order to handle XDG env variables and `filereadable()` which is more *readable* that `empty(glob())`:

```
" Bootstrap Plug 
let autoload_plug_path = stdpath('data') . '/site/autoload/plug.vim'
if !filereadable(autoload_plug_path)
  silent execute '!curl -fLo ' . autoload_plug_path . ' --create-dirs
      \ "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim"'
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
unlet autoload_plug_path
```

Comment: nit: Shouldn't this be the other way round? Source `.vimrc` then update the plugins?